# Which action called the component (Aura)

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, custom-button

I have an Aura component that I added to the page, that called every time a record opened.

The same component can be called from a button - (Buttons, Links, and Actions).

The component should behave differently - for example - some of the fields inside the component need to be disabled to edit when the record is opened, while when opening the component from a button can open them for edit.

is there a way to know where the Aura component opened from?

Many thanks

Comment: Summary: no. You need to create a wrapper component to pass in context information.

Comment: Thanks, @sfdcfox. did a wrapper and its worked,